# Android sdk file not found after running flutter doctor

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, sdk

The error on cmd says android SDK file not found: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3
  after running flutter doctor on flutter console.

Android Studio seems to work fine.

my sdk is located at C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras

What could be a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Android studio is working fine but your command line is not, the issue is likely your Path variables. Check out the ["Update Your Path"](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path) section of the Windows installation tutorial.

Comment: I added flutter\bin to the path, but still it shows the same(android SDK file not found) on running flutter doctor on flutter console.

Comment: After you updated the path, did you close and reopen the console window?

Comment: Yes, i did @JesseLawson

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Follow these three steps to solve the issue.

- Open SDK Manager
- Select Android SDK Build-Tools and uninstall it.
- Then reinstall the required SDK Build-Tools version (in your case 29.0.3)

That's all.
[image]